# Power Led Error in IBM/Lenovo M5 X3100 Server

Tags: hardware, ibm, power-supply-unit

I have a x3100 M5 Lenovo/IBM machine that is being used as file server. As of yesterday it had two 2.5" Samsung SSD's plugged in. Today I tried plugging in 2 x 3.5in 4TB hard drives, and when I tried to boot up the machine, I would hear the fans come on for a second and then switch off.

Once I opened up the machine, the light path system has the "power error LED" blinking. The [documentation](http://systemx.lenovofiles.com/mobile/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.lenovo.sysx.5457.doc%2Fr_configuring_server.html) unfortunately does not address what the blinking of this LED means. Does anyone know if this indicates that the power supply has failed?

If so, what kind of power supply unit should I purchase for a 4U Tower form factor cabinet? The label on my machine says "430 Watt Max Fixed Power Supply".

Answer (score 1):

Last week, I'd got the same problem like you. The led of my lenovo 3650 M5 blinked for a problem on a power supply.

I unplugged the cable with no results, I stay with the LED. I unplugged the power supply of his stack and re-insert it and the problem was resolved.

Wrong post edited by me. Kindly discard this suggested edit

Comment: when you say unplugged the power supply, do you mean unplugged it from the mother board?

Comment: Yes, unplug only the cable was insufficient. I went behind my server and I removed the power supply from the server.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work.